# WordPress - set term to all posts in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

I have some post type, let's say xxx with custom taxonomy. I want to set some term to all posts from this post type, in phpmyadmin.

So this is how I can get all posts ids:

`` SELECT ID FROM `wp_posts` WHERE `post_type` LIKE 'xxx'; ``

and this is how I can set term id 222 to post id 111.

`` INSERT INTO `wp_term_relationships` (`object_id`, `term_taxonomy_id`, `term_order`) VALUES ('111', '222', '0'); ``

But how can I set term id 222 to all selected posts? Is there something like foreach in sql?

I don't want to do it in php, because I need to execute it only once, not every time wordpress loads. I also don't want to do it by logging to wp admin.

Comment: Use `UPDATE` to update table data.

Comment: @jarlh, but how exactly? I need to add to the table a new row for every post id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I have the answer. Thank you Chat GPT! :)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE set_terms_to_posts()
BEGIN
    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
    DECLARE post_id INT;
    DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR SELECT ID FROM `wp_posts` WHERE `post_type` LIKE 'xxx';
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;
 
    OPEN cur;
 
    read_loop: LOOP
        FETCH cur INTO post_id;
 
        IF done THEN
            LEAVE read_loop;
        END IF;
 
        INSERT INTO `wp_term_relationships` (`object_id`, `term_taxonomy_id`, `term_order`) VALUES (post_id, 222, 0);
    END LOOP;
 
    CLOSE cur;
END//

DELIMITER ;

CALL set_terms_to_posts();
```